# Describe $\varphi\left( \mathbb{A}^2\right)$ by a conjunction of equations and inequations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\varphi \colon (x,y)\in \mathbb{A^2} \mapsto (x,xy^2,x^2y) \in \mathbb{A^3}$.
Let $(U ,V ,W )$ denote the coordinates on $\mathbb{A^3}$.
Assume that we know $\mathrm{cl}\left( \varphi\left(\mathbb{A}^2\right)\right) = Z \left( U^3V - W^2\right)$.

How can we describe $\varphi\left( \mathbb{A}^2\right)$ by a conjunction of equations and inequations?

I have actually no idea.

Thanks in advance.